# Trying to get Mouse to control camera in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm working with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtda9kkHQmU) on using a mouse to test a VR game, and for the most part I got it working, except it seems to "reset" the X or Y position every time I switch which axis I'm moving on.  For example, if I move the mouse x axis, it rotates the view, but then if I move the y axis, the x-position (.localRotation in the code) goes back to 0 (looking straight ahead in the original position).  Then if I move the x axis again, the y-position goes back to zero, but the x position picks up where I left it last time.

I have a feeling it isn't this code that's doing it, but I'll paste here just in case:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public InputActionReference horizontalLook;
    public InputActionReference verticalLook;
    public float lookSpeed = 0.25f;
    public Transform cameraTransform;
    float pitch;
    float yaw;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        horizontalLook.action.performed += HandleHorizontalLookChange;
        verticalLook.action.performed += HandleVerticalLookChange;
    }


    void HandleHorizontalLookChange(InputAction.CallbackContext obj)
    {
            yaw += obj.ReadValue<float>();
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(yaw * lookSpeed, Vector3.up);
            
    }

    void HandleVerticalLookChange(InputAction.CallbackContext obj)
    {
            pitch += obj.ReadValue<float>();
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(pitch * lookSpeed, Vector3.right);
            
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the rotation to explicit values based on a sum of mouse position or delta (isn't clear without seeing the Input Asset, but I assume delta), thus your rotation gets "reset" to the exact rotations only given by the current axis everytime.

Solution 1
Add the new rotation to your existing rotation by multiplying it to the left of your current rotation, e.g. `localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(...) * localRotation;`

Solution 2 (recommended)
Since Quaternions are not as intuitively understood as angles, Unity provides a convenience function called Rotate(axis, angle) on every Transform object
=> `transform.Rotate(<Vector3 as axis>, <your angle value>);`

In both approaches, however, the angle value should be calculated from mouse delta and not absolute screen position nor a sum of deltas.

Make sure to read through the Public Methods section on this manual page for a thorough understandung of how to manipulate transforms in Unity: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html